# iOS Screen Rotation Degraded When Shadows Are Visible

Tags: ios, core-animation, uiinterfaceorientation

This isn't in reference to any particular code, but I've noticed that when I have a UIView that has a shadow added to it's layer, the animation when rotating between interface orientations becomes much more laggy/choppy.

Has anyone noticed this issue or found a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are things which are very expensive in terms of CPU time. Check it out in Instruments some time.

- shadows
- bezier paths
- bezier paths with dashes (really expensive)

Thats not a comprehensive list. I suspect gradients will be there too.

If you find these things are degrading your animation or redraw you will need to toggle them in the `UIViewController` methods.

```
-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
//disable shadows + expensive drawing
}

- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
//enable shadows + expensive drawing
}
```

Comment: Thanks much good sir. It's really too bad though that they degrade performance so much. Perhaps displaying a pre-made UIImage of a shadow underneath the view instead of using the built-in shadow rendering.

Answer (score 2):

When using shadows, the `shadowPath` property of `CALayer` makes a very (!) noticable difference in performance, especially on the New iPad. Although I agree that disabling shadows when changing the display orientation is a good idea, it may be worth a try to just use `shadowPath` (if you do not use it already). Although the path can be any valid `CGPathRef`, in most cases this is what you want:

```
self.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.layer.bounds].CGPath;
```